# DeadlineExceededError with python django appengine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I have a task running which uses django.test.client to render pages:

```
from django.test.client import Client

client = Client()
resp = client.get(path, HTTP_HOST=settings.STATIC_SITE_DOMAIN, secure=True)
```

This successfully loops through pages and renders them to static files. However as the site has increased in size and page load times have increased, it now throws an error:

```
Rendering path /articles/funny-video-of-the-month/
Internal Server Error: /articles/ten-tips-for-december/
DeadlineExceededError: The overall deadline for responding to the HTTP request was exceeded.
```

I don't know whether this is the AppEngine task reaching it's 10 minute max length or the actual page http request reaching a 60 second limit. The documentation about the error is here:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors

There are other potential fixes on stackoverflow, but they are usually around urlfetch method which I don't believe is used.

Here are some potential fixes I can think of:

1) Alter existing timeouts on http requests made via django.test.client
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/test/client.py
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py

2) Split static generation into different tasks so each task doesn't run longer than 10mins

3) Try manual scaling option
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Instance_scaling_and_class

Any suggestions on how to fix would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: On app engine the time limit to respond to a request is 60 sec and to run a taskqueue is 10 min, so in your case it is exceeding 60 sec time limit.

Comment: ok great so it's more likely to be the http request rather than the task. In the docs it says: Automatic scaling: "60-second deadline for HTTP requests, 10-minute deadline for tasks" Manual scaling: "Requests can run indefinitely. Tasks can run up to 24 hours." so that may be the best option without re-engineering the code